# Predict Customer Next Purchase with Sequence

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, recommender-system

**Suppose I buy products:** [1,2,3,4]

**Another customer X bought:** [2,3]

Most probably **customer X next purchase** will be: 4

Sequence is very important in my problem

I tried ***association analysis*** using R, but it don't take under consideration the sequence

Please advise what algorithms I need to solve this?

Do I need to First do Clustering to find similar customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sequence problems, I generally used Recurrent Neural Network. It has a property to learn its values, which is based upon the previous state and current input.
**Since in your case sequence is important, you can use RNN. You can also try LSTM(type of RNN) cell.**

> And Additional Note: For product suggestion(where sequence is not
>   important) you can also use Apriori algorithm. This algorithm try to
>   build association between the products of a single order.

Comment: Could you please share with me useful reference or links with examples for  product suggestion using RNN

Comment: For series problem you can refer link "https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/", commonly used term is time series problem. In your case instead of time, you feed your product list(order is important as you said), in a order and it will predict the next product.